# Unknown or uninitialised column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is probably quite naive as I am new to R. I have a data frame and I am trying to use the `mutate` function to convert values in Hz in Semitones. This is what I have written :

```
rawdataST <- rawdata %>%
  mutate(f0st = (12*log2(FO)))
```

Where f0st is the name I want to give to the new column, and FO is the name of the column in my data frame with all the Hz values in it. I get the error message :

> Error: Problem with mutate() input f0st.
> x object FO not found
> ℹ Input f0st is (12 * log2(FO)).

After searching on here, I tried this:

```
rawdataST <- rawdata %>%
  mutate(f0st = (12*log2(rawdata$FO)))
```

But then I get this error message:

> Problem with mutate() input f0st.
> ℹ Unknown or uninitialised column: FO.
> ℹ Input f0st is (12 * log2(rawdata$FO)).

I don't understand what I am missing here! Help pretty please??!!!

Comment: Ccan you show the `str(rawdata)`.  May be you could check whether the column names is `FO` or `F0` i.e. number 0 or O- Orange

Comment: It's just what the error says: there's no columns called FO in your dataset, my best guess is that the actual name is F0 (F-zero)

Comment: You can also use `names(rawdata)`

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid... Indeed, I must have typed the letter instead of zero... Thanks guys!